# R - Big Data - vector exceeds vector length limit

Tags: r, bigdata

I have the following R code:

```
data <- read.csv('testfile.data', header = T)
mat = as.matrix(data)
```

Some more statistics of my testfile.data:

```
> ncol(data)
[1] 75713
> nrow(data)
[1] 44771
```

Since this is a large dataset, so I am using Amazon EC2 with 64GB Ram space. So hopefully memory isn't an issue. I am able to load the data (1st line works).
But as.matrix transformation (2nd line errors) throws the following error:

```
resulting vector exceeds vector length limit in 'AnswerType'
```

Any clue what might be the issue?

Answer (score 12):

As noted, the development version of R supports vectors larger than 2^31-1. This is more-or-less transparent, for instance

```
> m = matrix(0L, .Machine$integer.max / 4, 5)
> length(m)
[1] 2684354555
```

This is with

```
> R.version.string
[1] "R Under development (unstable) (2012-08-07 r60193)"
```

Large objects consume a lot of memory (62.5% of my 16G, for my example) and to do anything useful requires several times that memory. Further, even simple operations on large data can take appreciable time. And many operations on long vectors are not yet supported

```
> sum(m)
Error: long vectors not supported yet:
    /home/mtmorgan/src/R-devel/src/include/Rinlinedfuns.h:100
```

So it often makes sense to process data in smaller chunks by iterating through a larger file. This gives full access to R's routines, and allows parallel evaluation (via the parallel package). Another strategy is to down-sample the data, which should not be too intimidating to a statistical audience.

Comment: @Martin parallel evaluation might not be possible for all R functions. Example: glmnet. Atleast I am not aware if parallel implementation is possible for glmnet and that's what I need for my current data analysis

Answer (score 6):

Your matrix has more elements than the maximum vector length of 2^31-1.  This is a problem because a matrix is just a vector with a `dim` attribute.  `read.csv` works because it returns a data.frame, which is a list of vectors.

```
R> 75713*44771 > 2^31-1
[1] TRUE
```

See `?"Memory-limits"` for more details.

Comment: Just beat me to it. I've added the link to find this info in R.

Comment: @mnel: thanks for the edit. I also added some details about why `read.csv` works but `as.matrix` doesn't.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich so does that mean there is no way to make R handle a dataset as large as the one I have?

Comment: The development version of R allows vectors and hence matricies (total size, not individual dimensions) that are larger than 2^31-1. 'handle a data set' implies that you have to input all data, and that it has to be represented as a matrix; useful analysis can be done without either.

Comment: @MartinMorgan: can you add that as an answer and elaborate (or show an example) of how to create a matrix that large? Or is it supported out of the box?

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich it's pretty new, see R-devel in the R Internals manual and NEWS