# org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: eval failed while running R script from java

Tags: java, r, svm

I am getting the RserveExcpetion called org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException: eval failed while running the below code.

```
import org.rosuda.REngine.REXPMismatchException;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RConnection;
import org.rosuda.REngine.Rserve.RserveException;

public class Temp {

public static void main(String a[]) {
    RConnection connection = null;

    try {
        /* Create a connection to Rserve instance running on default port
         * 6311
         */
        connection = new RConnection();

        /* Note four slashes (\\\\) in the path */
        connection.eval("source('F:\\testFiles\\svm.R')"); //Here getting the exception
        int num1=10;
        int num2=20;
        int sum=connection.eval("myAdd("+num1+","+num2+")").asInteger();
        System.out.println("The sum is=" + sum);

    } catch (RserveException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (REXPMismatchException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
}
}
```

How to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

that is because the R function `myAdd()` was not initialized correctly by reading in the source file. Try the answer from here: [Calling R from Java using RServe weird error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18883846/calling-r-from-java-using-rserve-weird-error) using a try-catch statement to see the actual R error.